# Mixing data in abstract class when working in parallel

Tags: java, oop, jpa

I have a problem with my abstract class, I have an app for about 2000 users and many make calls at the same time to different classes, those classes share an abstract class

```
class A extends B{
    //Code
}
```

The inconvenience arises when in my abstract class I receive parameters to some of my methods that in this case all classes call these methods.

```
class abstract B {
    public int getResult(int b){
       return b+1;
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public int getValue(int a){
        int b = getResult(a);
        int c = b * 2 / 4;
        return c + 150;
    }
}
```

When several people in parallel enter the class 'C' and pass different parameters to the method getResult ends up mixing the data sent and returns erroneous data in the execution.

The option that I have found is to implement the getResult method in each class, but that makes me repeat code in each class and there are about 200 classes that implement that abstract class

I've read that with encapsulation I can avoid that, but I don't know if that's the option since I haven't worked on it.

I have used the **synchronized** but it has created many bottlenecks and response times have increased.

Comment: I think you are speaking of concurrency, not encapsulation.

Comment: Yes, exactly.
But reading about topics I have read part of the encapsulation but if I am confused is what I want to achieve understand how to solve.

Comment: In your example, none of the classes have any state. So, how could your methods end up mixing results, then? Please clarify

Comment: My classes are called by JPA so when they are called they call the methods that I show in the classes, but I have gotten the data mixed up, I don't know if it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need use synchronized in your getValue method to manage parallel access to yout method. Maybe this article can help you, have a simple example too: [https://dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-synchronization#:~:text=the%20credit%20method](https://dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-synchronization#:%7E:text=the%20credit%20method)

1. Note B class must have _"abstract" keyword before class.
2. Add "synchronized" in your getValue method

This way:

```
abstract class B {
    public int getResult(int b){
       return b+1;
    }
}

    class C extends B {
        public synchronized int getValue(int a){
            int b = getResult(a);
            int c = b * 2 / 4;
            return c + 150;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to comment that I had already used the synchronized but I think a bottleneck because of so many requests at the same time, But I appreciate the help and will correct the question since I don't mention the synchronizer issue